# emacs font: font installed but cannot set in emacs

Tags: emacs, fonts

I have installed font "Incosolata" into my linux (CentOS 6) , and i can set this font as default font for Terminal.

Then I add this in my .emacs file: `(set-default-font "Inconsolata")`

when emacs(24.5) start up , it shows:

```
error: Font not available, # font-spec nil nil Inconsolata nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ((:name . Inconsolata) (user-spec . Inconsolata))
```

and in options->Set Default Font... , I cannot find "Inconsolata", either.

Is there any options I missed? 
should I make some settings to let emacs recognize this font?

Many thanks for your help!

update_0：
I tried this , but not work :

```
(setq initial-frame-alist '(
  (font . "Inconsolata-14")
))
(setq default-frame-alist '(
  (font . "Inconsolata-14")
  ))
```

and them this method tried , still not work :

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :height 100 :family "Incosolata")))))
```

update_1:
here is how I install the font

```
wget https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/ofl/inconsolata/Inconsolata-Regular.ttf
mkfontscale 
mkfontdir  
fc-cache -fv
reboot
```

with fc-list :family , I can see there is font Incosolata

Comment: I need to select `-unknown-Inconsolata-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1` for the font. Try typing `M-x set-default-font Return -Inconsolata Tab` and see the options.

Comment: I've tried this method ,but in the list of fonts , there's still not Inconsolata. It seems that this font cannot be well recognized by emacs.

Comment: How did you install the font?

Comment: I've update my steps to install the font in the main feild of this question , would you please take a look at it ? so many thanks !

Comment: Hm, I've never done that. I just download the file to a directory mentioned in `~/.fonts.conf` and that's it.